# Powershell : Access Method of an Object Passed to a Function

Tags: pdf, powershell

I'm new to Powershell, and I have a problem when trying to access the method of an object I passed to a function.

What I don't understand is that I can access the fields of this object.

Here is my code :

```
Add-Type -Path .\itextsharp.dll

Function getText ($reader, $page)
{
    # WORKS : CAN ACCESS THE NumberOfPages FIELD HERE
    echo $reader.NumberOfPages

    # ERROR : CAN'T ACCESS THE GetPageContent METHOD
    return $reader.GetPageContent($page)
}

$reader = New-Object iTextSharp.text.pdf.pdfreader -ArgumentList "C:\toto.pdf"

# WORKS : CAN ACCESS THE NumberOfPages FIELD
for ($page = 1; $page -le $reader.NumberOfPages; $page++)
{
    # WORKS : CAN ACCESS THE GetPageContent METHOD
    $lines = $reader.GetPageContent($page) -join "" -split "`n"

    getText ($reader, $page)
}
```

Is it possible to access the method in a simple way ?

Comment: Doesn't seem possible.  The [ref] type only enumerates the values.  I usually see [ref] types used in functions to avoid scoping issues, but I don't see any potential scope issue here.

Comment: Ok, but how can I access GetPageContent from my Function ? Is there any other way ?

Comment: Just use $reader instead of [ref]$reader

Comment: Oh Idk what I've done, it was simple, but yesterday I tried this during hours, and I didn't success.
That's why I tried with REF.
Thanks.

Comment: I found my real problem, I called my Function like with getPageText($reader, $page), and I had to call without parenthesis getPageText $reader $page. Powershell is really mysthic to me. Sorry because when I posted on my problem I removed parenthesis, not thinking it could come from here. I'm gonna modify my question and add the answer, but Thanks, you really helped me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my problem, which was to pass the Object with all its Methods to a Function.

It did not work with this call :

```
getText ($reader, $page)
```

But I could not really explain why, but parentheses are important on a function call in Powershell :

```
getText $reader $page
```

Coming from JavaScript World, it is very strange to me, but this line works as expected, and I can now access the methods of **$reader** from the **getText** function.

Reference :
http://weblogs.asp.net/soever/archive/2006/11/29/powershell-calling-a-function-with-parameters.aspx

Answer (score 2):

The type of $reader is a:

```
System.Management.Automation.PSReference`1[iTextSharp.text.pdf.pdfreader]
```

Inside the function you need to reference it's `Value` property e.g.:

```
$reader.Value.NumberOfPages
```

That said, since you're not modifying what the variable `$reader` refers to, I'm not sure why you are passing by ref in this function.

Comment: What I want to access is GetPageContent method.
Doesn't seem possible with $reader.Value.GetPageContent.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and trying to solve my problem. I actually asked my question in a wrong way. My real problem was the Parentheses when calling the function, and passing arguments to it. Sorry for this.

Comment: Doh! Got so focused on the ref business that I completely missed you were only passing in `one` argument - an array with two elements.  Yeah, fairly common mistake in PowerShell.